# How to freez documents

Tags: records-management, archive

One of the reason SharePoint can not be used as a "real" archive, is the lack of methodes to freez or make the document permanent and not editable (and possibaly saved to PDA/A format in the process)

Have anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: Could you specify which version of SharePoint you'd like to have this feature enabled on?

Answer (score 0):

It can be used as an archive.  If you want to archive a document from your 'Active Document Library' do the following:

1. Make a choice column called `DOC ARCHIVE STATUS` and have 'active' and 'archive' as choices.
2. Make a separate Archive Document Library - this will be used to store archive documents.
3. Make a Sharepoint Designer workflow - use some logic, if `DOC ARCHIVE STATUS` equals `archive` copy document to another Document Library.  You can also make the workflow delete the original after the copy command has completed.
4. Edit the permissions on the Archive Document Library - so that no one can edit documents there except Sharepoint Administration.  Give users only 'read' permissions.

Then, Bob's your uncle, you have a Sharepoint archive.

BTW - this is only one way to do it.  There are other ways of approaching this too.

Further reading - look up Information Management Policy.  To get your started, you might find Kim Frehe's [excellent blog post](http://kimfrehe.com/category/sharepoint/) to be of use.